# Why is image leaving pixels after using flip function in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've started learning pygame recently. I would like to simulate rain in one of my project.
My problem is that raindrop in program leave traces. Program contains also pygame.display.flip() function but with no success. I had also program with ship which I can control and this is working correctly despite the code is nearly same.

Can someone explain me a reason?

Here is code. Thanks for help.

```
import sys
import pygame

class Rain:
    """Class to simulate rain."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize rain attributes."""

        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 650))
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.raindrop = Raindrop(self)

    def check_key_events(self):
        """Check key and mouse events."""

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def update_screen(self):
        """Update screen."""

        self.raindrop.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()

    def run_simulation(self):
        """Main loop for simulation."""

        while True:
            self.check_key_events()
            self.raindrop.movement()
            self.update_screen()

class Raindrop:
    """Class to represent single raindrop."""

    def __init__(self, rain_sim):
        """Initialize raindrop attributes."""

        self.screen = rain_sim.screen
        self.settings = rain_sim.settings
        self.screen_rect = rain_sim.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('raindrop.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def movement(self):
        """Function to move raindrop."""

        self.y += self.settings.raindrop_speed
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw raindrop at the current location."""

        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Settings:
    """Class that store settings."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Set settings for single parts of program."""

        self.raindrop_speed = 1.5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rain_sim = Rain()
    rain_sim.run_simulation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to draw the object and to update the display in every frame, it is also necessary to clear the display in every frame.
The entire scene is redraw in every frame in the main application loop. That meas, clear the display, draw the objects and update the display. The display can be cleared by performing [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) on the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object which is associated to the window. e.g:

```py
class Rain:
    """Class to simulate rain."""
    # [...]

    def update_screen(self):
        """Update screen."""

        # clear disaply
        self.screen.fill(0)

        # draw scene / draw object(s)       
        self.raindrop.blitme()

        # update display
        pygame.display.flip()
```